# Выбрать минимальное значение, но не ноль mySQL

Tags: mysql, запрос

В таблице есть столбец с цифрами. Некоторые из них - 0. Как одним запросом выбрать из столбца  минимальное не равное нулю значение, а также максимальное? Спасибо. UPD В выборку должны попасть нули тоже, но одновременно определить минимальное ненулевое.
Сейчас вот так, но минимальное всегда ноль получается

```
SELECT ... MIN(0+price) as min, MAX(0+price) as max FROM ...
```

Comment: `where price > 0`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin сорри, забыл добавить - в выборку должны попасть даже нули, но еще и отдельно определить минмиальное ненулевое

Comment: @Анатолий тогда для `MIN()` надо использовать подзапрос. Всё остальное оставить как есть, а вместо min: `(SELECT MIN(0+price) FROM … WHERE price > 0)`

Comment: `MIN(IF(price=0, NULL, price))`

Comment: Вы хотите в одной выборке получить данные разных уровней агрегирования, что идеологически неправильно. Лучше сделайте два отдельных запроса.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
create table test (id int,price int);
insert into test values  
 (1,1)
,(2,0)
,(3,3)
,(4,2);


select * 
  ,min(case when price<>0 then price else null end)over() minNot0
  ,max(price)over() maxPrice
from test;
```

Получится

| id | price | minNot0 | maxPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |